# What is the name/relevant details of this exponential-family related structure?

Tags: inference, mathematical-statistics

Suppose that $X$ comes from an exponential family
$$
p_\theta(x) = h(x)\exp(\theta x - A(\theta)),
$$
and that, conditional on $X$, $Y$ also comes from an exponential family of the form
$$
p_\eta(y\mid x) = h(y\mid x)\exp(\eta y - A(\eta, x)). 
$$

Just a pointer to a reference would be helpful. I'm not sure if this has a name, or even if it is an interesting structure, but it has popped up in some work and I feel like I should know any relevant details. Essentially, the canonical parameter for $Y|X$ is free of $X$.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I think this structure is somewhat vague and admits a lot of pretty run of the mill distributions. For example, let $X_1, X_2\sim Poisson(\theta)$ and let $Y=X_1+X_2$. Then Conditional on $X_1$, $Y$ has a Poisson distribution with mean shifted by $X$, which is still an exponential family. $Y$ as the sum of binomials or gammas also works.

Crucially though, the value of the canonical parameter for $Y$ may be different after conditioning on $X$ (as in the Poisson case above), but it's value doesn't depend on $X$. In fact, it's even possible that the conditional $Y$ could be exponential family but unconditionally not exponential family.

If the canonical parameter *did* depend on $X$, then what you'd have would be a $Y$ that was unconditionally a mixture distribution with a prior parameter that was a function of $X$.

HTH

Comment: That it admits a lot of "run of the mill" examples is why I thought there might be a name for it. The structure does have some inferential implications. And, indeed, $Y$ is not generally going to be in the exponential family marginally - if it was, I would just use the exponential family representation and be happy :)

Comment: What are the inferential implications? I'm curious about how it's come up. I've never given the structure much thought before so it could certainly be more interesting than I'm thinking about.